# How do I make a 3.6.2 python application that others can download?

Tags: cmd, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I wish to distribute my Python application to people who don't have Python installed.

I've tried pyinstaller, py2exe, and cx_freeze. I can create the .exe file using cx_freeze, but when I distribute it to other people, errors pop up and they cannot access my application.

Is there a better way to distribute my code other than "freezing it"?

Comment: Your first step is to actually post the errors

Comment: As this is a programming based forum, we also probably also need to see the py file, know the cxfreeze script options used and probably any distutils setup script information. If you used a third party installer to package your compiled file, _like Inno Setup_, then we may even need to know the options used with this setup program. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46066015/edit) facility to update your question as it is currently too broad to attract any reasonable answer.